# При нажатии на button у другого исчезают стили

Tags: javascript, button

Есть плеер с плейлистом и у него кнопки серий в виде button через JS и проблема в том что при нажатии на кнопку серии у другого button на странице исчезают стили. Как сделать, чтобы те стили, которые заданы у плеера только на нем имели эффект?

Скрипт плеера:

```js
var a, b, n, j, k = 1;
num = 0, nom = 0, nym = 0, pos = 0, seria = "&nbsp;Серия", chast = "&nbsp;Часть", server = "&nbsp;Сервер";
um = window.um || {};
(um = {
 create: function(e) {
  document.getElementById(e).innerHTML = '<div id="wrapper" onselectstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false;"><div id="player"></div><div id="panel"></div></div>';
  k = 1, num = 0, nom = 0, nym = 0;
  var c = document.createElement("div"),
   d = document.getElementById("panel");
  if(d != null) {
   c.id = "playlist";
   d.appendChild(c);
   d.innerHTML += '<div onmousedown="um.move(3)" onmouseover="um.move(1)" onmouseout="um.move(0)" id="r"></div><div onmousedown="um.move(4)" onmouseover="um.move(2)" onmouseout="um.move(0)" id="l"></div>'
  }
 },
 uplay: function(h, f, d) {
  var g, m = 1,
   e, c, l;
  if(d) {
   if(d == 1) {
    d = chast
   } else {
    if(d == 2) {
     d = server
    }
   }
  } else {
   d = seria
  }
  try {
   num = num + 1;
   l = document.createElement("button");
   l.setAttribute("title", num + d);
   l.setAttribute("class", "plclass");
   l.setAttribute("id", "id-" + num);
   l.setAttribute("type", h);
   l.setAttribute("name", f);
   if(d == chast || d == server) {
    nym = nym + 1;
    nom = nom - nym + num;
    if(k == 1) {
     k = k - 1;
     nom = nom + 1
    }
    l.innerHTML = nym + d
   } else {
    nom = nom + 1;
    l.innerHTML = nom + d
   }
   document.getElementById("playlist").appendChild(l)
  } finally {
   e = document.getElementById("id-" + num);
   e.setAttribute("onclick", "um.player('id-" + num + "');return false;");
   e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(document.getElementsByTagName("button")) {
     c = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
     for(g = 0; g < c.length; ++g) {
      c[g].setAttribute("class", "")
     }
    }
    e.setAttribute("class", "active")
   }, false)
  }
  setTimeout("um.move(2);um.player('id-1');document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].setAttribute('class','active');", 1700)
 },
 move: function(d) {
  var g, f, c, e = 0,
   h = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for(g = 0; g < h.length; g++) {
   e = e + h[g].clientWidth + 2
  }
  e = e - 425;
  if(d == 0) {
   clearTimeout(a);
   clearTimeout(b)
  }
  if(d == 1) {
   if(pos >= -e) {
    b = setTimeout("um.move(1)", 15);
    pos = pos - 5;
    document.getElementById("playlist").style.left = pos + "px";
    document.getElementById("l").removeAttribute("style")
   } else {
    clearTimeout(b);
    document.getElementById("r").setAttribute("style", "background:url(images/next.png) -122px 0 no-repeat;")
   }
  }
  if(d == 2) {
   if(pos <= -5) {
    a = setTimeout("um.move(2)", 15);
    pos = pos + 5;
    document.getElementById("playlist").style.left = pos + "px";
    document.getElementById("r").removeAttribute("style")
   } else {
    clearTimeout(a);
    document.getElementById("l").setAttribute("style", "background:url(images/prev.png) -120px 0 no-repeat;")
   }
  }
  if(d == 3) {
   if(pos >= -e) {
    f = setTimeout("um.move(3)", 10);
    pos = pos - 10;
    document.getElementById("playlist").style.left = pos + "px";
    document.getElementById("l").removeAttribute("style")
   } else {
    clearTimeout(f);
    document.getElementById("r").setAttribute("style", "background:url(images/next.png) -122px 0 no-repeat;")
   }
  }
  if(d == 4) {
   if(pos <= -10) {
    c = setTimeout("um.move(4)", 10);
    pos = pos + 10;
    document.getElementById("playlist").style.left = pos + "px";
    document.getElementById("r").removeAttribute("style")
   } else {
    clearTimeout(c);
    document.getElementById("l").setAttribute("style", "background:url(images/prev.png) -120px 0 no-repeat;")
   }
  }
  if(e <= pos) {
   document.getElementById("r").setAttribute("style", "background:url(images/next.png) -122px 0 no-repeat;")
  }
 },
 player: function(e) {
  var c = document.createElement("embed"),
   d = document.createElement("object");
  type = document.getElementById(e).getAttribute("type");
  if(em = document.getElementsByTagName("embed")[0]) {
   em.parentNode.removeChild(em)
  } else {
   if(ob = document.getElementsByTagName("object")[0]) {
    ob.parentNode.removeChild(ob)
   }
  }
  if(type == "0" || type == "") {
   c.height = "100%";
   c.width = "100%";
   c.setAttribute("allowScriptAccess", "always");
   c.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
   c.src = "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + document.getElementById(e).name;
   c.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
   document.getElementById("player").appendChild(c).style.background = "#000"
  }
  if(type == "1") {
   c.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
   c.src = "http://video.rutube.ru/" + document.getElementById(e).name;
   c.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
   c.setAttribute("wmode", "transparent");
   c.height = "100%";
   c.width = "100%";
   document.getElementById("player").appendChild(c).style.background = "#000"
  }
  if(type == "2") {
   c.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
   c.src = "http://www.24video.net/player/24.12.08/v24_play.swf";
   c.setAttribute("flashvars", "id=" + document.getElementById(e).name + "&idHtml=/video/xml/&idView=/video/view/&rootUrl=http://www.24video.net&playerCode=/video/playerCode/&playerPath=/player/24.12.08/v24_play.swf");
   c.setAttribute("allowscriptaccess", "always");
   c.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
   c.setAttribute("wmode", "transparent");
   c.setAttribute("quality", "high");
   c.height = "100%";
   c.width = "100%";
   document.getElementById("player").appendChild(c).style.background = "#000"
  }
  if(type == "3") {
   c.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
   c.src = "http://www.openfile.ru/video/player4/player.swf";
   c.setAttribute("flashvars", "videoID=" + document.getElementById(e).name);
   c.setAttribute("allowscriptaccess", "sameDomain");
   c.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
   c.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#000");
   c.setAttribute("quality", "high");
   c.height = "100%";
   c.width = "100%";
   document.getElementById("player").appendChild(c).style.background = "#FFF"
  }
  if(type == "4") {
   c.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
   c.src = "http://whitecdn.org/player/76fb851c2e71150f8f38a1af23c55b86/player.swf";
   c.setAttribute("flashvars", "videoID=" + document.getElementById(e).name);
   c.setAttribute("allowscriptaccess", "sameDomain");
   c.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
   c.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#000000");
   c.setAttribute("quality", "high");
   c.height = "100%";
   c.width = "100%";
   document.getElementById("player").appendChild(c).style.background = "#000"
  }
  if(type == "5") {
   d.data = document.getElementById(e).name;
   d.setAttribute("frameborder", "none");
   d.height = "100%";
   d.width = "100%";
   document.getElementById("player").appendChild(d).style.background = "#000"
  }
 }
})(um);
```

Comment: а какой html код этого " другого button на странице" ?

Comment: И отформатируйте код, который вы дали. Из этого однострочного мусора трудно что-то понять.

Answer (score 1):

Там в коде плеера такие конструкции:

```
c = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(g = 0; g < c.length; ++g) {
    c[g].setAttribute("class", "")
}
```

Этот код убирает классы у всех кнопок. Вам надо там дописать:

```
c = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(g = 0; g < c.length; ++g) {
    if(c[g].className != 'класс_вашей_кнопки'){
       c[g].setAttribute("class", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Все таки не работает, а возможно задать чтобы не убирал классы у кнопок и продолжало все работать?

Comment: Странно, почему не работает. Надо пробовать, может, дадите ссылку на сайт где эта проблема? Если нет, можете попробовать вообще закомментировать весь этот блок, заключите его в  /**/.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел, там еще есть строчка "setTimeout("um.move(2);um.player('id-1');document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].setAttribute('class','active');", 1700)", здесь тоже надо условие дописать по идее.

Comment: http://u414567.s03.wh1.su/ вот сайт, посмотрите. При посмотре фильма на верхний правий угол есть кнопка Добавить вот у нее и всей панели доб. коментариев стили пропадают при нажати на любую серию

Comment: Странно, при нажатии на серию действительно убирается класс у кнопки. Если не работает код выше (if(c.className != 'класс_вашей_кнопки')), можно попробовать добавить самой кнопке id ( <button id="toggle_addcomments"> и в стилях писать #toggle_addcomments ... Тогда класс уберется, но стили не затронутся по идее. Сейчас проверил - атрибут id кнопки с сериями не трогают

Comment: Кнопка добавить теперь нормально работает но пропадают все еще стили кнопок в форме добавления комментариев, нелзя как нибудь удалить функию убирания классов у всех кнопок??

Comment: Попробуйте просто удалить строчку c[g].setAttribute("class", "");  В коде плеера только эта строчка может классы у кнопок убирать. Если это не помогает, значит, где-то еще какой-то код у этого плеера, хотя это вряд ли.

Comment: Я сейчас в консоли браузера нашел этот код и закомментировал строку вот так:  "//c[g].setAttribute("class", "");" Это помогло, кнопки стили сохраняют, так что должно работать, именно в этом дело.

Comment: ДА да заработало, спасибо вам большое Максим!

Comment: @denubil не за что =)